# VSCODE multiples error with SSH extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

i have problem with VSCODE SSH : OUTPUT :

```
[07:00:06.173] Got password response
[07:00:06.173] "install" wrote data to terminal: "*********"
[07:00:06.225] > 
[07:00:06.419] > bash: bash : commande introuvable
[07:00:07.703] "install" terminal command done
[07:00:07.704] Install terminal quit with output: bash: bash : commande introuvable
[07:00:07.704] Received install output: bash: bash : commande introuvable
[07:00:07.705] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[07:00:07.707] Resolver error: Error: 
    at g.Create (c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:499734)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:497056)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:620589)
    at async c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:580447
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:583753)
    at async k (c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:577412)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:581124)
    at async c:\Users\p1err\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.109.0\out\extension.js:2:847283
[07:00:07.713] ------
```

it refuse to connect to this server, but with another server it's work. Thanks

Comment: read every single Q&A in https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Failed+to+parse+remote+port+from+server+output%22+site:stackoverflow.com and find the one your question is a duplicate of and close it as a duplicate of it, or if none are duplicate targets, edit your post to explain why.